# Call to a member function toSql() on integer

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a code:

```
$update= DB::table('Appraiser_commands')->where('cycle_id', $cycleid)->where('user_id',$userId)->update(['mode' => $mode,'Appraiser_commnd'=>$json])->toSql();
        echo $update;exit;
```

I am trying to convert laravel query to mysql using toSql()

But i got an error like

> Call to a member function toSql() on integer

Then i tried

```
 DB::table('Appraiser_commands')->where('cycle_id', $cycleid)->where('user_id',$userId)->update(['mode' => $mode,'Appraiser_commnd'=>$json])
         DB::enableQueryLog();
        $queries = DB::getQueryLog();
        dd(end($queries));
```

But it returns output as 'false' i dint get the expected output.I don't know why this happened.Any help would be appreciated.

Expcted output:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET Appraiser_commnd=value, mode=value2,...
WHERE cycle_id=some_value
```

Comment: echo this and not update echo DB::table('Appraiser_commands')->where('cycle_id', $cycleid)->where('user_id',$userId)->update(['mode' => $mode,'Appraiser_commnd'=>$json])->toSql();

Comment: @Exprator:thanks for the reply..but still the same issue..please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the query builder to output its raw SQL query as a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18236294/how-do-i-get-the-query-builder-to-output-its-raw-sql-query-as-a-string)

Comment: @MateiMihai i refer this link..but i dint get the expected output

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the raw sql for a laravel delete/update/insert statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45193727/how-to-get-the-raw-sql-for-a-laravel-delete-update-insert-statement)

Comment: You have to enable the query log before running the query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call `update()`, it executes the query and returns the number of affected rows (an integer). You're then calling `toSql()` on the integer. This is causing the error you are seeing.

If you're trying to see the SQL without running the query, you'll need to do this:

```
// start the query but don't execute it
$query = DB::table('Appraiser_commands')
    ->where('cycle_id', $cycleid)
    ->where('user_id', $userId);

// use the grammar object to get the update sql
$sql = $query
    ->getGrammar()
    ->compileUpdate($query, ['mode' => $mode, 'Appraiser_commnd' => $json]);
```

If you do want to execute the query, but also get the SQL, you can do this:

```
// start the query but don't execute it
$query = DB::table('Appraiser_commands')
    ->where('cycle_id', $cycleid)
    ->where('user_id', $userId);

// use the grammar object to get the update sql
$sql = $query
    ->getGrammar()
    ->compileUpdate($query, ['mode' => $mode, 'Appraiser_commnd' => $json]);

// actually run the update statement
$updated = $query
    ->update(['mode' => $mode, 'Appraiser_commnd' => $json]);
```

Additionally, you could view the sql in the query log, but you must enable the query log **before** executing the statement:

```
// enable the query log
DB::enableQueryLog();

// execute the update
DB::table('Appraiser_commands')
    ->where('cycle_id', $cycleid)
    ->where('user_id', $userId)
    ->update(['mode' => $mode, 'Appraiser_commnd' => $json]);

// view the query log
dd(DB::getQueryLog());
```

Comment: @JeffPuckett You're absolutely correct. I have updated the provided code to pass in the builder object. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: what is mode => $mode. Please provide complete answer. Link to a documentation would also be helpful

Comment: @Xitcod13 That comes from the code in the original post. The answer is as complete as the original question. Additionally, none of this is documented, so a link to the documentation doesn't exist.

Comment: no worries just the guidelines state that you should make the answer as useful for everybody as possible. So it would be slightly improved if you included the part of the code from the question that is being reused. Pity about the documentation stuff.

Answer (score 3):

Do the following:

a)At the start of the function :

```
DB::enableQueryLog();
```

b)After executing the query do this:

```
dd(DB::getQueryLog());
```

It will give the whole query

Answer (score 1):

```
    DB::enableQueryLog();    
$update= DB::table('Appraiser_commands')->where('cycle_id', $cycleid)->where('user_id',$userId)->update(['mode' => $mode,'Appraiser_commnd'=>$json])

    $queries = DB::getQueryLog();
    dd(end($queries)); // only last query
```

remove the toSql and try this

Comment: :it returns false only

Comment: that means there is an error with the query, try to find it

Comment: @Exprator-I know there is an error.that's why i am tried to convert it to sql.so i can find error easy

Comment: i dont know whether wrong query is printed or not, try without the end and check if you get all the queries

Answer (score 1):

Return type of [`update`](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_update) is `int` and [`toSql()`](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_toSql) expects an Builder instance.

If using `AND` in where clause you could change the query to the following and try dumping its sql as

```
$update = DB::table('Appraiser_commands')
            ->where(
                ['cycle_id', '=', $cycleid],
                ['user_id', '=', $userId]
            )->update([
                'mode' => $mode,
                'Appraiser_commnd' => $json
            ]);
```

If using `OR` in where clause you could try as

```
$update = DB::table('Appraiser_commands')
            ->where('cycle_id', $cycleid)
            ->orWhere('user_id', $userId)
            )->update([
                'mode' => $mode,
                'Appraiser_commnd' => $json
            ]);
```

After executing the query

```
$queries = DB::getQueryLog();
dd($queries);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can **not get** the **raw query** for the **update query** in Laravel **query builder** and `->toSql()` is only work for **select query**.
But if you want to get previous query which execute in laravel than follow this

[How to get the query executed in Laravel 5 ? DB::getQueryLog returning empty array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27753868/how-to-get-the-query-executed-in-laravel-5-dbgetquerylog-returning-empty-arr)